# О Боге в религиозном тексте: Он, Его, Божественное, или Помогите проверить цитату

Tags: прописная-строчная, цитата

У меня ЧП. Есть две цитаты - авторская и из Инета (единственное, что нашла). Если б в инетной не было ошибки, просто всё перерисовала бы, а так -

люди, помогите найти цитату со штампом "Уплочено"!

У автора:

> Ибо самый худший порок – незнание бога; способность же к познанию, его
>   желание и надежда не него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путем,
>   ведущем к благу идущего по нему. И повсюду тебя встретит бог, и
>   повсюду объявится он тогда, когда ты этого не ждешь, - бодрствующему и
>   спящему, плывущему и идущему по дороге, ночью и днем, говорящему и
>   молчащему; ведь нет ничего, чем бы не был он.
>
> Станешь ли теперь говорить: "Бог невидим?" Придержи свой язык! Ибо кто
>   более видим, чем он? Он сотворил все именно ради того, чтобы ты во
>   всем увидел его. Таково божественное благо, такова божественная
>   добродетель - то, что он проявляет через все. Ибо нет ничего, что
>   нельзя было бы увидеть, хотя бы среди бестелесного: ум видим в
>   мышлении, а бог – в творении.

В [Интернете](http://ezocircle.ru/wiki/11-um-k-germesu/):

> (21Ь) Ибо самый худший порок — незнание бога; способность же к
>   познанию, его желание и надежда на него являются кратчайшим и
>   наилегчайшим путем, ведущим к благу идущего по нему. И повсюду
>   встретит тебя бог, и повсюду объявится он тебе, там и тогда, когда ты
>   этого не ждешь, — бодрствующему и спящему, плывущему и идущему по
>   дороге, ночью и днем, говорящему и молчащему; ведь нет ничего, чем бы
>   не был он. (22а) Станешь ли ты теперь говорить: «Бог невидим»?
>   Придержи свой язык! Ибо кто более видим, чем он? Он сотворил все
>   именно ради того, чтобы во всем ты увидел его. Таково божественное
>   благо, такова божественная добродетель — то, что он проявляет себе
>   через все. Ибо нет ничего, что нельзя было бы увидеть, хотя бы и среди
>   бестелесного: ум видим в мышлении, а бог — в творении.

(Ога. Себе он проявляет.)

---

После моего вмешательства:

> Ибо самый худший порок – незнание Бога; способность же к познанию, его
>   желание и надежда на него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путём,
>   ведущим к благу идущего по нему. И повсюду встретит тебя Бог, и
>   повсюду объявится Он тебе, там и тогда, когда ты этого не ждёшь, –
>   бодрствующему и спящему, плывущему и идущему по дороге, ночью и днём,
>   говорящему и молчащему; ведь нет ничего, чем бы не был Он.
>
> Станешь ли ты теперь говорить: "Бог невидим?" Придержи свой язык! Ибо
>   кто более видим, чем Он? Он сотворил всё именно ради того, чтобы во
>   всём ты увидел Его. Таково божественное благо, такова божественная
>   добродетель – то, что Он проявляет **себя** через всё. Ибо нет ничего,
>   что нельзя было бы увидеть, хотя бы и среди бестелесного: ум видим в
>   мышлении, а Бог – в творении.

*Герметический корпус. Ключ Гермеса Трисмегиста*

---

Вот в этом предложении он-она-оно относится к Богу или к познанию?! к пути?!

> ...способность же к познанию, **его** желание и надежда на **него**
>   являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путём, ведущим к благу идущего по
>   **нему**.

Пожалуйста, любые ошибки, глазнушка, пропущенная ёшка, прописная-строчная - кричите!

И - **верна ли разбивка на два абзаца**?

Автор прислал фото страничек...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну не понимаю я этого "себе"!

---

---

***Дополнено после комментариев.***

> Ибо самый худший порок – незнание Бога; способность же к познанию Его,
>   желание Его и надежда на Него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим
>   путём, ведущим к Благу. И повсюду встретит тебя Бог, и повсюду
>   объявится Он тебе, там и тогда, когда ты этого не ждёшь, –
>   бодрствующему и спящему, плывущему и идущему по дороге, ночью и днём,
>   говорящему и молчащему; ведь нет ничего, чем бы не был Он.
>
> Станешь ли ты теперь говорить: «Бог невидим?» Придержи свой язык! Ибо
>   кто более видим, чем Он? Он сотворил всё именно ради того, чтобы во
>   всём ты увидел Его. Таково Божественное Благо, такова Божественная
>   Добродетель – то, что Он проявляет себя через всё. Ибо нет ничего, что
>   нельзя было бы увидеть, хотя бы и среди бестелесного: ум видим в
>   мышлении, а Бог – в творении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое "**его**" явно относится к "познанию", последующее **него** - с большой вероятностью к нему же (формально при капитализации могло бы и к "Нему", но в начале тезиса сильно акцентируется "порок незнания", отсюда можно вывести пожелание *надежды на знание* Бога), в конце "по **нему**" относится к "пути". Разбиение на абзацы оправдано, поскольку номера абзацев оригинала опущены (видимо, не нужна была строгая отсылка к источнику).

Comment: Сашечка, я совсем запуталась... Читай коммент к Люсе (твой увидела).

Answer (score 1):

> Ибо самый худший порок – незнание Бога; способность же к познанию, его
>   желание и надежда на него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путём,
>   ведущим к благу идущего по нему.

В моём понимании "к познанию Его":

Ибо самый худший порок – незнание Бога; способность же к познанию Его, желание и надежда на Него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путём, ведущим к благу идущего по нему.

Comment: А к чему (кому) при такой пунктуации отнести "желание"?

Comment: Люсенька! Две советские публикации научного текста! Слова переставлять мы не можем, хоть я и согласна всей душой! Если не было зловещего ***себе***, сомнений не возникло бы: делаем по книжке. А так... В крайней я растерянности. И насчёт дробления на абзацы - опять же против солидного издания...

Comment: Это же перевод, русских переводов было два. Вот второй - слова совсем другие, но смысл - как мы понимаем: https://books.google.fr/books?id=x0fYjLUJ3noC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false (читать 11 - К Уму )

Comment: Наихудший порок состоит в незнании 6oжecтвeннoro'''; но быть способным знать (Менар: знать Его), желать знать, надеяться знать - это верный способ достигнуть Блага путем прямым и легким. И, следуя этим путем, ты встретишь Его везде, ты везде Его увидишь, там и тогда, где и когда вовсе этого не ожидаешь, наяву, во сне, в море, в дороге, ночью, днем, говоря, молча. Ибо нет ничего, что не было бы Богом. http://apokrif.fullweb.ru/hermes/germ11.shtml

Comment: Здесь явно "способным знать Его" (по Менару), желать знать Его, надеяться знать Его, просто убрали повтор. И абзацы пронумерованы: 21 a, 21b, 22a, 22b.Советским изданиям как раз доверять не стоит, их издавали  атеисты, особо в смысл не вдумываясь, лишь бы грамотно было. Вот это "себе" - как они "ять" переделали в "е", смешав русский падеж со старославянским, как "смесь французского с нижегородским". Я никак не вникну, чем занимается ваш автор, он что, издаёт апокрифы гностицизма? Или статью о гностицистах пишет ? Что нужно-то от нас, если он просто перепечатывает чей-то перевод апокрифа?

Comment: Александр, мне видится пунктуация верной, потому что по смыслу " способность же к познанию Его,  желание (познать Его) и надежда на Него" просто перевод такой неудачный.

Comment: Люсенька, читаю уже вёрстку - не могу угомониться. В цитате из апокрифа "в незнании 6oжecтвeннoro'' - как понимать шестёрку? *Б* прописное или строчное?  Можно ли в цитате сделать так: *...способность же к познанию Его, желание Его и надежда на Него являются кратчайшим и наилегчайшим путём, ведущим к Благу.* Как вообще с этим работать?

Comment: @Людмила И что с "божественным" - благом, добродетелью? Я вставлю в подвопросье, но не поздно переделать и отозвать, - отзовитесь, пожалуйста! И что с названием главы? У автора **Герметический корпус. Ключ Гермеса Трисмегиста**, а я нашла **11. Ум к Гермесу**?

Comment: Видимо, в связи с новыми требованиями все религиозные символы писать с прописной, верно будет с большой буквы и эти символы: незнание Божественного,  Божественное Благо, такова Божественная Добродетель.

Comment: Галя, я вот нашла, посмотри:  https://vk.com/pages?oid=-26807962&p=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82_11  . Кстати, здесь божественное с маленькой буквы, но ведь это тоже чьё- то творчество. Цитата эта всё же из 11 трактата "Ум к Гермесу", а "Ключ" - трактат 10. Так что нужно: Герметический корпус.  Ум к Гермесу

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

- "способность же к познанию". "Познание" является житейским уделом, следует заменить на "понимание".
- "способность же к познанию(,) его желание". Здесь с запятой вопрос. Может надо "способность же к познанию Его(,)"? Потому что далее выходит что у бога желание.