# Вы без трепета воспримете "портал входа"?

Tags: лексика

> Пишу именно о портале входа - то есть наличник, пилястры и
>   антаблемент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> И все учебники такие - это проф. лексика. Если я буду переводить её на
>   твой русский - люди знающие подумают, что я безграмотна в области
>   истории архитектуры)))

Наш ответ:

— Ога, и (что интересно) незнающие подумают то же самое. Как я.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB)

> **ПОРТАЛ**, -а; м. [от лат. porta - ворота] 1. Архитектурно оформленный большой проём, обычно являющийся входом в здание.
>
> ---

Люди! Если вас ничто не нервирует в портале входа, оставим слово специалиста. Но адресат - широкая аудитория.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, это будет выглядеть странно, но "портал входа" мне не нравится, а вот **входной портал**  - нормально, потому что есть  портал каминный, есть портал сцены.

Значение слова **портал** по Строительному словарю:

> Портал - Архитектурно оформленный и богато украшенный резьбой и т. п.
>   дверной проем монументального здания.

http://tolkslovar.ru/p14818.html

Т.е. портал - это П-образный проём, ниша, её обрамление, в технике это - П-образная часть конструкции или машины, напр.опорная часть портального подъемного крана, станины металлорежущего станка.

Иногда, говоря, что портал - это богато оформленный дверной проём, мы имеем в виду  само убранство, видимо, Ваш  автор тоже имел в виду убранство, это метонимия, как, например, "не то на серебре - на золоте едал" вместо золотой посуды - золото.

Может быть, Вашему автору не принципиально будет изменить на "**входной портал"** - это будет корректно, а **портал входа** получается, что проём входа - она же не это хотела сказать, а убранство входа...

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание плохо воспринимается, поскольку напрашивается противопоставление мифическому парному "*порталу выхода*" - возникает ассоциация с похожими компьютерными терминами. На самом же деле "**портал**" здесь - конкретная архитектурная *форма* организации *входа*. Для пояснения читателю лучше представить его примерно так:

> Вход туда представляет собой *портал* - то есть наличник, пилястры и
>   антаблемент.

Comment: Саш, приди сюда, а: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449377/%D0%9E-%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82/449383#449383